# Is there a O(n) algorithm to build a max-heap?

Tags: algorithm

Given a array of number, is there a O(n) algorithm to build a max-heap?

Comment: Maybe if your input is already ordered properly.

Comment: @Frustrated...: It's not ordered.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, like in this code:

```
for (int i = N/2; i >= 0; --i)
    push_heap(heap + i, N - i);
```

(`push_heap` is a function that accepts a pointer to a heap and the heap size and pushes the top of the heap until the heap conditions are respected or the node reaches the bottom of the heap).

To get why this is O(N) look at the complete binary tree:

- 1/2 elements (last level, i > N/2) are pushed down at most 0 steps -> N/2 * 0 operations
- 1/4 elements (last-1 level, i > N/4) are pushed down at most 1 step -> N/4 * 1 operations
- 1/8 elements (last-2 level, i > N/8) are pushed down at most 2 steps -> N/8 * 2 operations
  ...

  ```
    N/4 * 1 + N/8 * 2 + N/16 * 3 + ... =

    N/4 * 1 + N/8 * 1 + N/16 * 1 + ... +
              N/8 * 1 + N/16 * 2 + ... =

    N/4 * 1 + N/8 * 1 + N/16 * 1 + ... +    // < N/2
              N/8 * 1 + N/16 * 1 + ... +    // < N/4
                        N/16 * 1 + ... +    // < N/8
                                   ... =    // N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + ... < N
  ```

Hope that math is not really too complicated. If you look on the tree and add how much each node can be pushed down you'll see the upper bound O(N).

Comment: Man, you made the math far simpler than the WIKI article! Thanks a ton!

Comment: What for this input: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. I think it should be O(nlogn)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is: [Building a heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap).

Comment: +1. More for the tone of the answer than the answer itself :)

Comment: Your own link suggests that it is not possible. It should have said no there isn't...

Comment: @Peter: Quote from the link: "Therefore, the cost of heapifying all subtrees is: [snip equations] O(n)"

Answer (score -1):

If you use a [Fibonacci Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) you get [amortized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) O(1) insertion.  You can accordingly build a max heap in amortized O(n) from an array.

The implementation of such, I leave as an exercise*.

<sub>*Though, there are linked example implementations on the Wikipedia page.</sub>

Answer (score -4):

I don't think so. I think the best you can do is O(log n) or a little better with something like a fib heap.

Comment: `O(log n)` is `O(n)` (i.e., if `f` is `O(log n)` then `f` if `O(n)`).

Comment: I think he must have meant O(n log n)?

Comment: That's not clear to me. I think inserts in a Fibonacci heap are amortized `O(1)` and so building is amortized `O(n)`.

Comment: Building binary heaps bottom-up is `O(n)`.