# Build a sorted list from a maximum heap in O(n * log(log(n)))?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heap

I have a maximum heap represented in an array `A` , and I have the following question  :

```
Is it possible to build a sorted list , based on the maximum 
heap - A - in O(n*log(log(n))) ?
```

My answer : No we can't ! we can always run on `A` and execute MergeSort in  `O(n*log(n))` 
or a QuickSort in `O(n*log(n))` (worst case `O(n^2)`) .

I thought also maybe to build the actual heap based on `A` , this would take `O(n)` , and then extract from there all the elements in `O(n*log(n))` , but I gained nothing here .

At the moment I can't see any option for `O(n*log(log(n)))` , any ideas ?

Comment: Mergesort in O(n)? That's not possible in general.

Comment: I find it very hard to answer this question without doing your homework for you. (Too bad, because it's a fun exercise :)

Comment: @larsmans: +1 for the creative answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a max-heap in an array form then using something like insertion sort on that array should yield pretty good results. A max heap in array form is nearly sorted (descending) and the best case for insertion for is O(n) when the array is nearly sorted. It'll still has a O(n^2) worst case but I don't think you'd ever hit the worst case.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's not possible:
There is an algorithm to build a max-heap in o(n) (look here [Is there a O(n) algorithm to build a max-heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787252/is-there-a-on-algorithm-to-build-a-max-heap))
So if you could make a heap in o(n) and then sort it in o(n*log(log(n)),
you could get a sort algorithm that works in o(n*log(log(n)), which is not possible if you got  no initial information about your input.

Comment: I would just add emphasis that it is impossible to sort more quickly than O(N*log(N)) when you only have a comparison operator. O(N*log(N)) is the theoretical lowest bound for comparison sorts.

Comment: This [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Performance_limits_and_advantages_of_different_sorting_techniques) article contains more information about why this is the case.