# Extracting k largest elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heap

If I have n integers, is it possible to list the k largest elements out of the n values in O(k+logn) time? The closest I've gotten is constructing a max heap and extracting the maximum k times, which takes O(klogn) time. Also thinking about using inorder traversal.

Comment: Why do you want O(k + log n)? You need to traverse it at least once then at least O(n).

Comment: If the collection is unsorted, you have to examine all n integers. I don't see how one could possibly have a solution that's O(k + log n). Note that just constructing a max heap is already O(n).

Comment: How about using an AVL tree?

Comment: @Y.P It does not matter what you use, you have to look at each element at least once which means your effort is in Omega(n).

Comment: @ Y.P How does that help, creation of the tree itself will take nlgn time

Comment: @Y.P also "The closest I've gotten is constructing a max heap and extracting the maximum k times, which takes O(klogn) time" is not accurate, to construction of heap itself  O(N) so your overall complexity becomes O(N) + O(klgn)

Comment: @AvishekBhattacharya Better is to use a min heap that stores only the k largest elements this gives an effort of O(n log k).

Comment: @Henry yes, However if k is big enough you will end up same complexity of the sorting. Apart for QuickSelect I don't see any better ways to solve this

Comment: This can be done in O(n log k). See http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/

Answer (score 3):

Ways to solve this problem.

1. Sort the data, then take top k. Sorting takes `O(n lg n)` and iterating over the top k takes `O(k)`. Total time: `O(n lg n + k)`
2. Build a max-heap from the data and remove the top k times. Building the heap is `O(n)`, and the operation to remove the top item is `O(lg N)` to reheapify. Total time: `O(n) + O(k lg n)`
3. Keep a running min-heap of maximum size k. Iterate over all the data, add to the heap, and then take the entirety of the heap. Total time: `O(n lg k) + O(k)`
4. Use a selection algorithm to find the k'th largest value. Then iterate over all the data to find all items that are larger than that value.

   a. You can find the k'th largest using [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) which has an average running time of `O(n)` but a worst case of `O(n^2)`. Total average case time: `O(n)` + `O(n)` = `O(n)`. Total worst case time: `O(n^2) + O(n) = O(n^2)`.

   b. You can also find the k'th largest using the [median-of-medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) algorithms which has a worst case running time of `O(n)` but is not in-place. Total time: `O(n)` + `O(n)` = `O(n)`.

Comment: There is an in place variation for median of medians, which swaps data within the array to avoid allocating memory. Stack space is used due to recursion. It's O(n), but the constant factor is large.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Divide and Conquer** technique for extracting kth element from array.Technique is sometimes called as  **Quick select** because it uses the Idea of **Quicksort**.

**QuickSort**, we pick a `pivot` element, then move the pivot element to its correct position and `partition` the array around it. The idea is, **not to do complete quicksort**, but stop at the point where pivot itself is k’th smallest element. Also, not to recur for both left and right sides of pivot, but recur for one of them according to the position of pivot. The worst case time complexity of this method is **`O(n^2)`**, but it works in **`O(n)`** on average.

Answer (score -1):

Constructing a heap takes O(nlogn), and extracting k elements takes O(klogn). If you reached the conclusion that extracting k elements is O(klogn), it means you're not worried about the time it takes to build the heap.

In that case, just sort the list ( O(nlogn) ) and take the k largest element (O(k)).

Comment: This is incorrect. You can construct a heap in O(n) time.

Comment: How do you build a heap in O(n)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787252/is-there-a-on-algorithm-to-build-a-max-heap