# Time Complexity of Build Heap

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, heap, priority-queue

I am trying to understand the time complexity that C++ STL priority_queue have for building a heap. For build a heap, time complexity should be O(n). Suppose if we are having an vector of n elements and we want to build a max heap from that vector. Code will be like this -

```
vector<int> vec{3,4,5,1,2};
priority_queue<int> pq;

for (auto v : vec) {
pq.push(v);
}
```

The push operation takes O(log n) time. It looks to me as O(nlogn) time complexity. But the above code snippet just build a heap for the first time from the vector. How the complexity is O(n) for the above case i.e building a heap.

Edit : If the above code snippet is O(nlogn) so I want to know the code for building a heap using priority_queue c++ stl in O(n).

Comment: If `vec` contains `n` elements then time complexity would be `O(nlogn)`

Comment: but we use priority_queue to build heap like this and say time complexity is O(n) for building a heap. why it is said then ?

Comment: Note that `O(log(n))` time complexity is simply a statenebt about an upper limit for the time complexity of the operation. The operation may actually happen faster and only take that long in rare cases. If the runtime if `O(log(n))` for `O(n/log(n))` of the calls and `O(1)` for the rest, you've got `O(n)` total complexity. (Keyword amortized time complexity) (Note: I haven't taken a look at this specific example and checked, if the mentioned complexities are actually correct)

Comment: Btw: I think the time complexity of the insertions is only mentioned for passing all elements at once to the constructor, not for using a loop to insert the elements one by one. Check the build heap step for heapsort; this should be the logic used: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort

Comment: The implementation you've written is O(n log n).  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1793961/2166798 for the O(n) algorithm.  Explanations for why it works are given in that post, but there are dozens of other descriptions on the internet as well.

Comment: Similar code is written here : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-k-closest-points-to-origin-using-priority-queue/?ref=rp and it says time complexity is O(n) and O(nlogn). Can you explain why ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this algorithm for building a Heap of an input array A.

```
BUILD-HEAP(A) 
    heapsize := size(A); 
    for i := floor(heapsize/2) downto 1 
        do HEAPIFY(A, i); 
    end for 
END
```

This upper bound `O(nlg(n))`, though correct, is not asymptotically tight.

We can derive a tighter bound by observing that the running time of Heapify depends on the height of the tree ‘h’ (which is equal to lg(n), where n is number of nodes) and the heights of most sub-trees are small.

We can derive a tighter bound by observing that the running time of Heapify depends on the height of the tree ‘h’ (which is equal to lg(n), where n is number of nodes) and the heights of most sub-trees are small.

Please refer to this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-of-building-a-heap/) , for full explanation and mathematical proof.

Comment: Thats fine. I am looking how priority_queue works in O(n) for building a heap